# Javascript - turning if statement into switch statement

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert an if statement into a switch statement using javascript. This is the working if statement:

```
      if(!error1(num, a_id) && !error2(num, b_id) && !error3(num, c_id) && !error4(num, d_id)) {
    a.innerHTML = num;
```

Any tips on how to put this into a switch statement would be great. Thanks

Comment: It is usually an `if/else if/else` chain that is a candidate for conversion to a `switch`.  This is only a single (although compound) `if` condition.  It doesn't need to be converted to a switch.

Comment: Impossible without seeing the code for `error1`, `error2` etc

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you had `if (x == a || x == b || x == c)` then you could make it `switch (x) { case a: ... case b: ... case c: ... default: ... }`, but here you have `&&` and not `||`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* make this a `switch`, but it's unclear why you would want to. On first glance, this isn't the kind of situation (selecting amongst a set of values and doing something different for each of them) that you use `switch` for.

Here's how, though I don't recommend it:

```
switch (false) {
    case !error1(num, a_id):
    case !error2(num, b_id):
    case !error3(num, c_id):
    case !error4(num, d_id):
        // Do nothing
        break;
    default:
        a.innerHTML = num;
        break;
}
```

This works in JavaScript, but not in most other languages that have `switch`. The reason it works is that the `case` labels are evaluated when the execution point reaches them, and they're [guaranteed to be evaluated in source code order](http://es5.github.com/#x12.11). So you're switching on the value `false`, which will first be tested (using strict equality, `===`) against the return value of `!error1(num, a_id)`, and then if that doesn't match, against `!error2(num, a_id)`, etc.; if none of them matches, then they all evaluated `true`, and the code in the `default` block runs.

Comment: I never thought I'd see a `switch` _obfuscate_ an `if` rather than _clarify_ it.

Comment: This doesn't do the same thing as the original code.  This will succeed if _any_ of the error functions returns `false`, but the original code succeeds if _all_ of the error functions return `false`.  One fix would be to change the `case` conditions to `error1(num, a_id)`, etc., and move the successful code to the `default` block (see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FumKn/1/)).

Comment: @CheranShunmugavel: Oops, I could have sworn he was using `||`, but sure enough, it's `&&`. **Thanks!** Fixed, but I think we're all agreed that a `switch` is not the way to do this. :-) Also, note that your fiddle isn't *quite* correct, because `switch` uses `===` so we have to defend against `errorX` returning "truthy" and "falsey" values rather than actual `true` and `false`. See above, I do that by continuing to use `!` but matching against `false` rather than `true`.