# js - is it possible to have two elements on the switch condition?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, frontend

I have two variables, and I want to have the same behavior for both. for now I have this:

```
switch(var1){
case 0:
var1 = "a";
break;
}

switch(var2){
case 0:
var1 = "a";
break;
}
```

I want to know if is it possible something like this:

```
switch (var1, var2){
case var1 == 0:
var1 = "a";
case var2 == 0:
var2 = "a";
break;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not the more readable `if (var1 === 0 || var2 === 0) ...`?

Comment: But the `switch(var1, var2)` would work?

Comment: @hefojah390 - No. The point is, why not use the appropriate control flow statement (`if`) rather than the inappropriate one (`switch`)?

Comment: Yes, it's possible ([detals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555964/javascript-turning-if-statement-into-switch-statement)). No, it's not a good idea. :-)

Comment: I thought of switch case because I have to change the value of 8 possible options, from 0-7. It works fine using switch(var1) case 0...1..2..3... but at the moment I do it twice, one for each variable. I'm looking for clean code, do you think if statement would be a better option? I'm a newbie lol

Comment: @hefojah390 This is what we call an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). We need more context in order to give you better alternatives. (Although questions asking to make code more clear are generally off-topic on Stack Overflow. You might be able to find help with that on [codereview.se].)